# Symbol of Fourier transform

Tags: fourier

[image]

Hello. Is there any command that allows to write the Fourier transform like in the picture?
The command  `$\widehat()$` leaves it this way, but I would like the symbol to appear in the spot of the exponent (top right).

Answer (score 1):

I hope I interpret your question right, but as far as I see, you want something like this:

```
\documentclass{scrarticle}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \left(\frac{Q}{\beta}\right)^{\wedge}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I put the ^ at the position of the exponent. If you ever wonder about a symbol you can visit the detexify website and draw the symbol.